# How to temporary adjust date/time in Linux shell

Tags: linux, date, time

I want to write some testscripts that create some files and execute commands that change behaviour depending on the current date. For testing purposes I would like to change the time to different dates (in the past and future) and check the behaviour.

Is it possible to change the date exclusively just for a singe shell-session, or fool a single application about the current date? - how could this be done?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

this can be done to a program with [libfaketime](http://www.code-wizards.com/projects/libfaketime/) which is preload library i.e. `LD_PRELOAD`.